# Delphi Custom TImage Component - MouseEnter, MouseLeave in component

Tags: delphi, components, controls, mouseevent, timage

I'm trying to build a component based on `FMX.Objects.TImage`. I want the permanently assigned images by `MultiResBitmap.Items` to change without having to use `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` in the application. Of course, I will use the constructor and the destructor.

I'm a beginner, and maybe I don't understand something. I've been trying for a week now, and I can't detect the mouse over the component and assign events correctly to it. I temporarily used `ShowMessage()` for the test.

Theoretically, this code should probably work and not work. Tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```pascal
unit ImageCustoms;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, vcl.Controls, FMX.Objects, FMX.ImgList, vcl.Dialogs, vcl.Graphics, FMX.ExtCtrls;

type
    TImageCostoms = class(TImage)
private
  { Private declarations }
    FOnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var msg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var msg: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
protected
  { Protected declarations }
    procedure DoMouseEnter; virtual;
    procedure DoMouseLeave; virtual;
public
  { Public declarations }
    //constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    //destructor Destroy; override;
published
  { Published declarations }
    property OnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseEnter write FOnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseLeave write FOnMouseLeave;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TImageCostoms]);
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.CMMouseEnter(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  ShowMessage('Enter');
  DoMouseEnter;
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.CMMouseLeave(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  ShowMessage('Leave');
  DoMouseLeave;
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.DoMouseEnter;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMouseEnter) then
  ShowMessage('Enter');
  FOnMouseEnter(Self);
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.DoMouseLeave;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMouseLeave) then
  ShowMessage('Leave');
  FOnMouseLeave(Self);
end;

{constructor TImageCostoms.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  MultiResBitmap.Items[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('focus0.png');    // .\img\i.png
end;

destructor TImageCostoms.Destroy;
begin
   inherited Destroy;
end; }

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't mix VCL and FMX units together in your own units. VCL and FMX are not designed to be used together.  And since FMX is cross-platform, don't use `Winapi` units in your code unless you are writing *Windows-specific* code (which you are not, in this situation).

You don't need to handle the `CM_MOUSE(ENTER|LEAVE)` messages directly, the framework already does that internally for you. And you don't need to redeclare the `OnMouse(Enter|Leave)` events, they already exist and are `published` in `TImage`.

All you really need to do is `override` (not redeclare) the existing virtual `DoMouse(Enter|Leave)` methods from `Timage`, eg:

```pascal
unit ImageCustoms;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Objects, FMX.ImgList, FMX.ExtCtrls;

type
  TImageCostoms = class(TImage)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure DoMouseEnter; override;
    procedure DoMouseLeave; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    //constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    //destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TImageCostoms]);
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.DoMouseEnter;
begin
  ... 
  inherited;
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.DoMouseLeave;
begin
  ...
  inherited;
end;

{constructor TImageCostoms.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  MultiResBitmap.Items[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('focus0.png');    // .\img\i.png
end;

destructor TImageCostoms.Destroy;
begin
   inherited Destroy;
end; }

end.
```

Don't use `ShowMessage()` to debug component code, especially in events that react to keyboard/mouse focus changes. If you want to see debug messages, use `OutputDebugString()` or equivilent instead, and then look for the messages in the IDE's Output window. Or, just make display changes in your UI, like color changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it helped me, I was trying very uphill. In fact, in FMX it is simple and everything works. Thank you very much. I write the virtual keyboard support for the program, the whole is just a transparent button changing the focus slightly. Thanks again. For posterity, for now, it looks like this, I will try to add support from the global ImageList.

````
interface
uses
 System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Objects, FMX.ImgList, vcl.Dialogs, System.UITypes;
type
    TImageCostoms = class(TImage)

private
  { Private declarations }
    procedure DoMouseEnter; override;
    procedure DoMouseLeave; override;

protected
  { Protected declarations }

public
  { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

published
  { Published declarations }

end;

procedure Register;

implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TImageCostoms]);
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.DoMouseEnter;
begin
  inherited ;
  MultiResBitmap.Items[1].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('focus1.png');
end;

procedure TImageCostoms.DoMouseLeave;
begin
  inherited;
  MultiResBitmap.Items[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('focus0.png');
end;

constructor TImageCostoms.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  width:=45;
  height:=45;
  MultiResBitmap.Items[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('focus0.png');
end;


end.```
````

Comment: If you are thinking about having all theese images in some ImageList then why don't you go and simply use [TSpeedButton](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TSpeedButton) which you can connect to AnyImage list and then simply change the image index to show desired image. Or perhaps simply use SpeedButton with only one image and additional effect to reach this slight focus effect you are talking about. This way you reduce the number of images required by your application and get gradual transition between focused and unfocused states. This is worth checking out.